# dropdown-toggle in my thymeleaf isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I use spring boot, thymeleaf and bootstrap. This is my partial code in thymeleaf

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li th:class="${page == 'home' ? 'active' : ''}"><a
        th:href="@{/}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
            Home</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul></li>
</ul>
```

and this code for includes css and javascript file

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />

<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js}"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    th:src="@{/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

Why is the dropdown-toggle in my thymeleaf not working?

Comment: Thymeleaf doesn't have anything to do with that, your dropdown doesn't even include any thymeleaf fragments. Are you absolutely sure that your jquery is correctly included? You can easily verify this by checking the developer console of your browser. If it isn't included correctly you should see something like "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Also that <script>..</script> part isn't necessary for bootstrap dropdowns to work.

Comment: Be sure that your code is working with dummy HTML / without adding "th:" . It will help you to check whether your jquery plugin is woking.

Comment: when I checked my browser, I found this message "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery", what should I do ?

Comment: Verify that your jquery file exists at the path you specified (correct folder/file name)

Comment: [Solved], I have two files (header.html fragment and index.html), after I include jquery to index.html and header.html fragment my dropdown-toggle is working, not enough include jquery only in header.html fragment but also in index.html , thank all